# One Line RegEx to Both Include and Exclude

Tags: regex, google-analytics, google-analytics-filters

I need to write an expression that matches all URLs containing ".pdf", ".zip" and ".docx" but exclude any URL containing "/l/" in Google Analytics.

I know it's fairly simplistic, but I can't find a good example to extrapolate from.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give some examples of all cases?

Comment: Matching URLs is going to be quite tricky just because of the amount of variation. Can you make up an example?


Maybe something like:
[\w\.:]+\.[a-zA-Z]*/[\w\.]+?(\.pdf|\.zip|\.docx)[^\s]*

this will match a url that starts out words/numbers/periods/colons, the period between the domain name and the top level domain (.com/.edu etc). I added the colon in case a port was required. then it should match the directory structure and stop when it sees a pdf

Comment: The way I find easiest to regex google analytics is to do the "regex" on the page and then send a custom dimension to google analytics that you can filter. For example in `/l/` your google analytics can send a custom dimension called **exclude = 1** and in google analytics you can easily filter this out

Comment: Do you need this for ad-hoc filters in the reports or for (permanent) view filters (they seem to support a slightly different set of regex features and what you need might not be possible with ad hoc filters) ?

Answer (score 1):

Because of the poor support for negative lookaheads, I wound up finding another way to accomplish the same end goal.  I used Google Tag Manager to create a tag that only fires when both conditions are met.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to have a negative lookahead at the beginning to filter out any occurrence of `/l/`, then you can put anything else you want to positively match the rest of the url.

`(?!.*\/l\/)http://.+(\.pdf|\.zip|\.docx)`

Comment: While Google has apparently re-introduced negative lookahead in their regex implementation (they had been missing for quite some time) this seems to work only in the view filters, not the filter box in the reports (https://plus.google.com/+SimoAhava/posts/b3UXzSNu1AX).